# angularjs $compile service and ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Basically what I'm trying to do is build a directive that would take array as an isolate scope object. Build html iterating through the array with ng-repeat and compiling using $compile service against the directive's scope which would then be pushed into the content attribute of the popover. It works fine when ng-repeat is applied to the immediate parent node of the references. Fails when not. Can someone enlighten why it wouldnt work. Thanks in advance

Plunkr url: http://plnkr.co/edit/i5DlOWgHbyC8YovgKvt6?p=info

```
HTML 
<a working data-names="['cat','dog','mouse']">Click to get a basic popover -    working</a>
<br/>
<a not-working data-names="['cat','dog','mouse']">Click and you will get nothing</a>

JAVASCRIPT
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
}).directive("working", function($log,$compile,$http){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{
            names:'='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            $log.log(scope.names);//Logs Names
            var html = "<p><a ng-repeat='name in names'>This is a {{name}}</a></p>";
            var popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope);
            $log.log(popOverContent);//Logs p.ngscope properly
            var options = {
                content: popOverContent,
                placement: "top",
                html: true
            };
            $(elem).popover(options);
        }
    };
}).directive("notWorking", function($log,$compile,$http){
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope:{
            names:'='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
            $log.log(scope.names);//Logs Names
            var html = "<p ng-repeat='name in names'><a>This is a {{name}}</a></p>";
            var popOverContent = $compile(html)(scope);//Logs only a comment 
            var options = {
                content: popOverContent,
                placement: "top",
                html: true
            };
            $(elem).popover(options);
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apprently has to do with the popover structure not the scopes since both directives keep their ngrepeat in the same scope level, it appears that the popover needs to have only one root element in its template in the second example you are building several root elements
the only update was tha instead of

```
var html = "<p ng-repeat='name in names'><a>This is a {{name}}</a></p>";
```

i used

```
var html = "<div><p ng-repeat='name in names'><a>This is a {{name}}</a></p></div>";
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/eMGQFykGjEImzXFA0ffh?p=preview

Comment: cool.. Thanks it worked.. but is it anywhere documented that popover wud need a single root element ?

Comment: not that i've read it, but i have found this problem on directives that has set replace flag to true.

Comment: not necessarily, compile function should only be used if you are going to modify the html before is "compiled" and linked, in this case is just a case of wrapping the desired template content in a single tag.